# How to monitor the Raspberry PI 3 Health information?

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot

I am working on Simple IOT application using Raspberry PI 3 having windows 10 IOT core. The IoT application will work fine. But after few days my IoT device will stop to read the data from connected sensors. Because my IOT device will shut down sometimes, then I am thinking like for example if hundreds of IoT device will placed at different locations then how I can monitor which IOT device will work properly or not.

I know every connected device having the Windows Device Portal to monitor the CPU, I/O, Memory and Network. But I want to monitor all connected devices at time from one location.

So, please tell is there any API’s to monitor the Raspberry PI 3 health info.

Comment: You will need some kind of software ontop of the Pi to do this all.

Comment: @ppumkin Can you please tell me which software do in need to install on  top of the Raspberry PI 3.

Comment: oh right.. I meant probably some kind of software your make your self.